# Testing uniswapV2 swap function with hardhat

Tags: solidity, uniswap, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, sushiswap

I wrote a smart contract in solidity and want to test it with hardhat, but I don't know how to solve this issue and sorry at the beginning, it could be a very long post.
My smart contract looks like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "./IBalancerVault.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

contract TestSwap {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    address private owner;
    address public sushiRouter;

    constructor(
        address _sushiRouter,
    ) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        sushiRouter = _sushiRouter;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function balance(address token_address) external view returns (uint256) {
        console.log("TOKEN ADDRESS:");
        console.log(token_address);
        uint256 Balance = IERC20(token_address).balanceOf(address(this));
        console.log("Token Balance: ", Balance);
        return Balance;
    }

    function swapExactTokensForTokensSushi(
        uint256 _amountIn,
        uint256 _amountOutMin, 
        address _tokenIn,
        address _tokenOut,
        uint256 deadline
    ) public returns (uint256) {
        console.log(_amountIn);
        console.log(_amountOutMin);
        console.log(_tokenIn);
        console.log(_tokenOut);
        console.log(deadline);
        require(
            IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(sushiRouter, _amountIn),
            "approve failed."
        );
        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = _tokenIn;
        path[1] = _tokenOut;
        uint256[] memory amounts = IUniswapV2Router02(sushiRouter)
            .swapExactTokensForTokens(
                _amountIn,
                _amountOutMin,
                path,
                address(this),
                deadline 
            );
        console.log(amounts[1]);
        return amounts[1];
    }
}
```

So now I want to test the swap function after funding my contract with a bit of Matic (0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010).

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const {
  IERC20,
} = require("../artifacts/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol/IERC20.json");
const token_Address_wmatic = "0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270";
const token_Address_matic = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010";
const router_sushi = "0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506";
const balancer_vault = "0xBA12222222228d8Ba445958a75a0704d566BF2C8";

describe("test", () => {
  let Contract, owner, addr1, addr2, addr3;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    [owner, addr1, addr2, addr3] = await ethers.getSigners();
    factory = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestSwap");
    Contract = await factory.deploy(router_sushi);
    await Flashloan.deployed();
  });

  describe("Test functions", async () => {
    it("Should test swap function", async () => {
      let addr = addr1;
      let balance_signer = await addr.getBalance();
      const gasPrice = await ethers.provider.getGasPrice();
      console.log("Gas Price: ", gasPrice);
      console.log(
        "Address 1 BEFORE: ",
        ethers.utils.formatUnits(balance_signer.toString(), 18)
      );
      let balance_contract = await Contract.balance(token_Address_matic);
      console.log("MATIC BALANCE BEFORE: ", balance_contract);
      await addr.sendTransaction({
        to: Contract.address,
        value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("100", 18), // Sends exactly 10 matic
      });
      balance_signer = await addr.getBalance();
      console.log(
        "Address 1 AFTER: ",
        ethers.utils.formatUnits(balance_signer.toString(), 18)
      );
      balance_contract = await Contract.balance(token_Address_matic);
      console.log(
        "MATIC BALANCE AFTER: ",
        balance_contract / 1_000_000_000_000_000_000
      );
      //Swap to WMATIC - Only swap 90 out of 100 to be sure and set amount outmin very low (to not revert)
      let amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits("90", 18);
      let amountOutMin = ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", 18);
      let tokenIn = token_Address_matic;
      let tokenOut = token_Address_wmatic;
      let deadline = 90000; //Will be added to the block.timestamp
      await expect(
        Contract.swapExactTokensForTokensQuick(
          amountIn,
          amountOutMin,
          tokenIn,
          tokenOut,
          deadline
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWith("Error1");
      await expect(
        Contract.swapExactTokensForTokensQuick(
          amountIn,
          amountOutMin,
          tokenIn,
          tokenOut,
          deadline
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(MyContract, "CustomError 2");
      
    });
  describe("Receive Tokens", async () => {
    it("Should send wmatic tokens", async () => {
      let addr = addr1;
      let balance_signer = await addr.getBalance();
      const gasPrice = await ethers.provider.getGasPrice();
      console.log("Gas Price: ", gasPrice);
      console.log(
        "Address 1 BEFORE: ",
        ethers.utils.formatUnits(balance_signer.toString(), 18)
      );
      let balance_contract = await Contract.balance(token_Address_matic);
      console.log("MATIC BALANCE BEFORE: ", balance_contract);
      await addr.sendTransaction({
        to: Contract.address,
        value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("100", 18), // Sends exactly 10 matic
      });
      balance_signer = await addr.getBalance();
      console.log(
        "Address 1 AFTER: ",
        ethers.utils.formatUnits(balance_signer.toString(), 18)
      );
      balance_contract = await Contract.balance(token_Address_matic);
      console.log(
        "MATIC BALANCE AFTER: ",
        balance_contract / 1_000_000_000_000_000_000
      );
      //Swap to WMATIC - Only swap 90 out of 100 to be sure and set amount outmin very low (to not revert)
      let amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits("90", 18);
      let amountOutMin = ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", 18);
      let tokenIn = token_Address_matic;
      let tokenOut = token_Address_wmatic;
      let deadline = 90000; //Will be added to the block.timestamp
      const gasEstimate =
        await Contract.estimateGas.swapExactTokensForTokensSushi(
          amountIn,
          amountOutMin,
          tokenIn,
          tokenOut,
          deadline
        );
      console.log(gasEstimate);

      let tx = await Flashloan.swapExactTokensForTokensSushi(
        amountIn,
        amountOutMin,
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut,
        deadline,
        { gasLimit: gasEstimate * 50 }
      );
      console.log(tx);
      console.log("Amount Out should be: ", am_out);
      balance_contract = await Contract.balance(token_Address_matic);
      console.log(
        "MATIC BALANCE AFTER: ",
        balance_contract / 1_000_000_000_000_000_000
      );
      balance_contract = await Contract.balance(token_Address_wmatic);
      console.log(
        "WMATIC BALANCE AFTER: ",
        balance_contract / 1_000_000_000_000_000_000
      );
    });
  });
});
```

By testing I get the error:

```
1) test
       Test functions
         Should test swap function:
     AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with Error1, but other exception was thrown: ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
```

and:

```
2) test
       Receive Tokens
         Should send wmatic tokens:
     Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266","to":"0x58Be5Ec7F96Ef12B6d8B41611AdE2205F0AD1df7","data":"0x040e3b97000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004e1003b28d92800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008ac7230489e8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000000d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf12700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002328","accessList":null}, error={"name":"ProviderError","code":-32603,"_isProviderError":true,"data":{"message":"Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string","data":"0x"}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.1)
```

Can someone help me solving this issue?

Would be amazing, I don't know what to do anymore...

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

swapExactTokensForTokensSushi function is private.
You should make local unit tests for your contract before deploying to live nets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I have to say, that was my mistake by inserting a older version... Actually I have set it as public and I have corrected the question. Error stys the same